# Problema implementando SSL a página web para acceder a ella con protocolo HTTPS

Tags: http, ssl, https

Tras activar el certificado de seguridad SSL desde el hosting, ahora se puede solicitar satisfactoriamente casi todas las direcciones de mi página web desde el protocolo https. Ahora bien, encuentro un problema en alguna de las rutas que no sé de dónde puede venir. ¿Alguna idea?

En aquellas rutas donde se produce el problema, aunque se presenta bien el contenido de la página, igual que al llamarlo desde el protocolo HTTP, el problema es el siguiente, aparece el HTTPS con un doble tachado y el navegador dice que no es seguro.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He sido cuidadoso reemplazando toda llamada de HTTP en el código HTML por llamadas a HTTPS para que no ocurra el error de contenido mixto.

Comment: Es probable que tengas alguna imagen siendo llamada desde un `http`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema solucionado.

Tras activar el SSL y reemplazar, de los ficheros HTML, CSS..., cualquier llamada a HTTP por HTTPS, aparece el error de la imagen (https con doble tachado) al solicitar la web.

En el código HTML se hacían uso de hojas de estilo CSS, como la siguiente:
https://static-cdn3-w2.webnode.com/files/2x/2xj/2xj5m0.css?ph=69bba5380a . Al reemplazar su llamada http por https genera el error de la imagen (https con doble tachado).

La solución ha sido acceder a la dirección web de esa hoja de estilos, copiar todo su contenido y pegarlo en un fichero.css el cual se subirá al servidor y se llamará de forma local desde el HTML. Reemplazando así la llamada de un href que apuntaba a un lugar inseguro por una llamada href que apunta a un fichero.css propio.

Answer (score 1):

Es un problema de contenido mixto, puede ser que hayas buscado en el codigo, pero puede estar en alguna librería javascript, dentro de un CSS o en otro lugar que no te has dado cuenta.

Lo más fácil es abrir la herramientas del desarrollador del explorador (F12) y en la solapa Network buscar cual es la llamada a un http

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Efectivamente hay llamadas a HTTP en algún código CSS, JS... los cuales son recursos solicitados a desarrolladores externos ( p. ej. https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js o https://static-cdn3-w2.webnode.com/files/2x/2xj/2xj5m0.css?ph=69bba5380a ). Entiendo que son llamadas a HTTP que no pueden ser reemplazadas por desarrolladores particulares. Solo queda resignarse a tener una página no segura si hago uso de esos recursos verdad?

Comment: Hola Xjavi, no, no te resignes. Cambiale las llamadas por HTTPS todas funcionan en cualquier servicio más o menos serio